# Random Numbers based on the ANU Quantum Random Numbers Server

Tags: ruby, random

I have been asked to use the [ANU Quantum Random Numbers Service](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/index.php) to create random numbers and use Random.rand only as a fallback.

```
 module QRandom

   def next
     RestClient.get('http://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?type=uint16&length=1'){ |response, request, result, &block|
       case response.code
         when 200
           _json=JSON.parse(response)
           if _json["success"]==true && _json["data"] 
             _json["data"].first || Random.rand(65535)
           else
             Random.rand(65535) #fallback
           end
         else
           puts response #log problem
           Random.rand(65535)   #fallback
       end
     }
   end

 end
```

Their [API](https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/api-demo.php) service gives me a number between 0-65535. In order to create a random for a bigger set, like a random number between 0-99999, I have to do the following:

```
(QRandom.next.to_f*(99999.to_f/65535)).round
```

This strikes me as the wrong way of doing, since if I were to use a service (quantum or not) that creates numbers from 0-3 and transpose them into space of 0-9999 I have a choice of 4 numbers that I always get. How can I use the service that produces numbers between 0-65535 to create random numbers for a larger number set?

Comment: Aside: You really need to remove some of those extra "silent" fallbacks inside the parsing. Also, not sure why you don't just use Ruby's SecureRandom from standard library - even if that is the fallback, it could be better choice - although you have not explained the reason why you want the external source.

Comment: If you're only getting 16 bits at a time, you need to get more than one to have a large range. In C, that would just be `uint32_t r = ((get16() << 16) | get16());`. Don't know Ruby.

Comment: Since you don't need help with Ruby, JSON, networking, or even quantum physics, your question boils down to "How do I generate a random number between 0 and 99999 when all I have is a service that gives me 16 random bits at a time?"  I am sure this problem has been solved before and there must be a good RFC somewhere, or at least another StackOverflow question.

Comment: `(QRandom.next.to_f*(99999.to_f/65535)).round ` is a 1-to-1 map, so it does not produce "a random number between 0-99999". It randomly selects one of 65536 numbers that are between 0 and 99999. It cannot return 1, 4, 7, etc.: `(0..9).to_a.map { |n| (n.to_f*(99999.to_f/65535)).round } #=> [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14]`.

Comment: This service is an interesting curiosity, but I don't know why one would use it. Good pseudo random number generators produce sequences that pass demanding statistical tests for randomness.  They also have a "seed", making them reproducible, which is almost essential for debugging. Lastly, I think there are physicists who would argue that that ANU Quantum's numbers are not truly random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 65535 is 1111111111111111 in binary, you can just think of the random number server as a source of random bits.  The fact that it gives the bits to you in chunks of 16 is not important, since you can make multiple requests and you can also ignore certain bits from the response.

So after performing that abstraction, what we have now is a service that gives you a random bit (0 or 1) whenever you want it.

Figure out how many bits of randomness you need.  Since you want a number between 0 and 99999, you just need to find a binary number that is all ones and is greater than or equal to 99999.  Decimal 99999 is equal to binary 11000011010011111, which is 17 bits long, so you will need 17 bits of randomness.

Now get 17 bits of randomness from the service and assemble them into a binary number.  The number will be between 0 and 2**17-1 (131071), and it will be evenly distributed.  If the random number happens to be greater than 99999, then throw away the bits you have and try again.  (The probability of needing to retry should be less than 50%.)

Eventually you will get a number between 0 and 99999, and this algorithm should give you a totally uniform distribution.

Comment: This seems like the obvious approach to me but I don't have any official sources to cite.  There should be an RFC about this, or maybe you could look at how `Random` and `SecureRandom` are implemented in Ruby, since they probably get their randomness from a source of random bits.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't even consider throwing away faulty values, I was trying to map them to valid ones or limit the range I was generating. This seems like the correct answer to me. And indeed the probability of getting a valid number is ALWAYS <= 50%

Comment: Wonderful answer, David! What a pity you have to throw away some random numbers, but you can take some solace in the knowledge that you are not alone: if `n` is not a power of 2, *all* random number generators that return one of `n` numbers throw away numbers.

Comment: Had to check my series there, but using exactly 19 bits to cover a 19-bit number is the less efficient use of available bits. Instead, draw 22 bits (in general 2 or 3 more than needed is probably good enough), and reject values > 8*max. Use modulo arithmetic to get number in range. This uses an expected 23.46 bits per sample - for the worst case - whilst your suggestion uses 37.77, or almost a whole extra draw per number in OP's scheme.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It is in fact possible to not throw away any random numbers generated, and be much less wasteful in terms of bits, as I explain in my answer (an update to the comment, technically I was out by 1 bit).  So for example if max range was `2**18 + 1` - a bad case for above answer - the above answer would use ~ 37.77 bits per number, and the second part of my answer would use 19.00

Comment: @NeilSlater, thank you for correcting me. I was doubly-wrong: it appears that in Ruby and other languages, that is simply not an issue. When computing `rand(x)`, Ruby's first step is to compute `rand`, a random  number between zero and one. For any given probability distribution function, F, a random variate can be generated by computing G(`rand`), where G is the inverse of F (`F(G(x)) = x`) (assuming F is monotonic). `rand(x)` merely performs that computation for a uniform discrete distribution that ranges from zero to `x-1`; i.e., `rand(x) = (x*rand).to_i`.

Comment: Cary, that behavior in Ruby sounds awful, especially if you want a 256-bit random number, which has way more bits than a float.  Does SecureRandom do a better job?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: AFAICS, SecureRandom uses a variant of your approach for generating integers, including retries. This makes sense -although they could do better with sparing use of bits, that's not a normal problem to have, even with cryptographic random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the individual numbers you are getting as 16 bits of randomness. To make larger random numbers, you just need more bits. The tricky bit is figuring out how many bits is enough. For example, if you wanted to generate numbers from an absolutely fair distribution from 0 to 65000, then it should be pretty obvious that 16 bits are not enough; even though you have the range covered, some numbers will have twice the probability of being selected than others.

There are a couple of ways around this problem. Using Ruby's `Bignum` (technically that happens behind the scenes, it works well in Ruby because you won't overflow your Integer type) it is possible to use a method that simply collects more bits until the result of a division could never be ambiguous - i.e. the difference when adding more significant bits to the division you are doing could never change the result.

This what it might look like, using your `QRandom.next` method to fetch bits in batches of 16:

```
def QRandom.rand max
  max = max.to_i # This approach requires integers
  power = 1
  sum = 0

  loop do
    sum = 2**16 * sum + QRandom.next
    power *= 2**16
    lower_bound = sum * max / power
    break lower_bound if lower_bound == ( (sum + 1) * max ) / power
  end
end
```

Because it costs you quite a bit to fetch random bits from your chosen source, you may benefit from taking this to the most efficient form possible, which is similar in principle to [Arithmetic Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) and squeezes out the maximum possible entropy from your source whilst generating unbiased numbers in `0...max`. You would need to implement a method `QRandom.next_bits( num )` that returned an integer constructed from a bitstream buffer originating with your 16-bit numbers:

```
def QRandom.rand max
  max = max.to_i # This approach requires integers
  # I prefer this:  start_bits = Math.log2( max ).floor
  # But this also works (and avoids suggestions the algo uses FP):
  start_bits = max.to_s(2).length
  sum = QRandom.next_bits( start_bits )
  power = 2 ** start_bits

  # No need for fractional bits if max is power of 2
  return sum if power == max

  # Draw 1 bit at a time to resolve fractional powers of 2
  loop do
    lower_bound = (sum * max) / power
    break lower_bound if lower_bound == ((sum + 1) * max)/ power
    sum = 2 * sum + QRandom.next_bits(1) # 0 or 1
    power *= 2
  end
end
```

This is the most efficient use of bits from your source possible. It is always as efficient or better than re-try schemes. The expected number of bits used per call to `QRandom.rand( max )` is `1 + Math.log2( max )` - i.e. on average this allows you to draw just over the fractional number of bits needed to represent your range.

Comment: This makes sense and seems correct. I feel like the requirements of the question are just bad, though, because how many api requests might this make in the worst case scenario? Does speed not matter at all?

Comment: You mean [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Bignum.html).  Also, that's just an implementation detail.  Most programmers can just concern themselves with the `Integer` class.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Thanks, corrected (was thinking perl for some reason). Yes Bignums only come into it in that you don't need to care about overflowing your integer type, but worth noting because you won't get away with the short-cut in many other languages.

Comment: @ptd - it works pretty efficiently for low max values, you will only see extra calls in the ratio where the values would be ambiguous. If this is for security that could lead to timing-based attacks though.

Comment: I should have been clearer: in Ruby, Bignum is a subclass of Integer, and Integer has no upper or lower bounds.

Comment: I looked at your updated answer and it just isn't clear that it will give a uniform distribution.  Maybe it will, but you should try to explain why.  Also, using floats to solve integer problems might lead to rounding errors eventually.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: There are no floats used in any calculations (although one way of thinking about it is that the solution generates a potentially infinitely long float). There's no maybe about the uniform distribution, I didn't just make this up to solve the OP's problem. The best explanation is in the link to Arithmetic Coding wikipedia article. A full explanation of how it works with examples would take a whole answer by itself. The short explanation (check your divisions until you have enough bits that the answer is never ambiguous) is already in the answer.

Comment: `Math.log2(x)` returns a float according to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Math.html#method-c-log2).  You can get the bit length of an integer using a simple loop and bit shifting instead.

Comment: @DavidGrayson:That float is not used in any of the arithmetic, there is a `floor`. The bit length is the same either way you calculate it, and how it is calculated (in fact even if it is calculated - it is just an optimisation to reduce the number of divides) is not relevant to how the algorithm works. It will even work (in the sense that the distribution is uniform, but perhaps less efficiently in terms of wasted bits) if the value returned is wrong due to rounding errors.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: I adjusted the code to show it working without any Float rounding, to avoid the issue (although I still assert it is a non-issue). It also avoids some non-needed divides (I should have used `ceil`, but `floor` was left in whilst chasing an earlier bug). I suggest if you want to discuss how/whether this works as I say further, we open a question perhaps on CS Stack Exchange - I am happy to open that if you are really interested to see proof (or a debunking of my code)?

Answer (score 0):

How about asking for more numbers? Using the **length** parameter of that API you can just ask for extra numbers and sum them so you get bigger numbers like you want.

```
http://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?type=uint16&length=2
```

You can use inject for the sum and the modulo operation to make sure the number is not bigger than you want.

```
json["data"].inject(:+) % MAX_NUMBER
```

I made some other changes to your code like using SecureRandom instead of the regular Random. You can find the code here:

https://gist.github.com/matugm/bee45bfe637f0abf8f29#file-qrandom-rb

Comment: The problem is that this won't be uniform unless MAX_NUMBER happens to be a power of 2.   The results will be skewed towards the lower end of the output set.